Customize datalabels with Excel VBA
I am trying to use VBA to add datalabels to a graph.
I have this code that is working very well to add datalabeles to all the series that I have in the graph.
Sub Apply_Data_Labels()
    
  'Applies data labels to all
  'data series on the set chart
      
  'Set number format of data labels
  
Sheets("Grafico Pivot").Unprotect
  
  Const NumFormat = "#.##0"
  
   
  Dim Cht As Chart
  Dim Ser As Series
   
  'Set the chart
  Set Cht = Sheets("Grafico Pivot").ChartObjects("Chart 1").Chart
  
  'Apply data lables
  
For Each Ser In Cht.SeriesCollection

  Ser.ApplyDataLabels
  Ser.DataLabels.NumberFormat = NumFormat
  Ser.DataLabels.Font.Size = 10
    
Next Ser
  
  Sheets("Grafico Pivot").Protect DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True, Scenarios:=True
    
End Sub

Now I have a new challenge. I need to create a Graph where the datalabel can have only a limited number of values, from 1 to 20. For each number I need to display a particular text code (as in the attached image)

How can I do this?
I tried to use the If cause but I was not able to implement the right code.

In order to show labels instead of the value you don't even need VBA.

Expand your data table by one column that will contain the label values that you want to display for that data point.
Fill that column using the LOOKUP formula.
Add data labels to your graph the normal way.
Right click on a data label, select "Format Data Labels..."
From the opening side-panel, select "Value From Cells"
Excel will then open a popup asking you to select the range for the label values, where you select your new column
De-select "Value" from the side panel

If you insist or depend on doing it per VBA, this is a code draft assuming your data was in A2:B13 so far with C being the new label column and Ser being the Series object you labelled using Ser.ApplyDataLabels like in your question:

    ' [...]
    Ser.ApplyDataLabels
    ' This was what you already had

    ' New code starts here
    Ser.DataLabels.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.InsertChartField msoChartFieldRange, "='Grafico Pivot'!$C$2:$C$13", 0
    Ser.DataLabels.ShowRange = True
    Ser.DataLabels.ShowValue = False

